# Show/Hide tableView Header on UIButton click inside UIViewController in Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have a `tableView` and created `tableViewHeader` using `Xib`. I am able to show `tableViewHeader` on `UIViewController`. Outside `tableView` their is a `UIButton` so when i click that button headerView will hide,`tableView` will scroll up upto its position and when i again click the same button `tableView` header will be shown & `tableView` will scroll down. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What code have you written? Please read [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `boolean` for the state of the UIButton Action and based on `TRUE` & `FALSE` you can hide the `UITableViewHeader`.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      if boolObj  {
        return 0.0
    }else{ 
        return 50.0
    }
```

**On Button Action**

```
 if boolObj {
     boolObj = false
 }else{
     boolObj = true
 }
 tblOutlet.reloadData()
```

Comment: suppose i have a tableview header of height 410 so will i work with it @Ravi B

Comment: @anuj you can use your value. I have mentioned (50) as a example. You can use your value which ever it is. (in this case 410)

Comment: initially tableview header will be hidden, and when i click it will show the tableviewheader and tableview will scroll down again if i click same button tableviewheader will be hidden and tableview will scroll up @Ravi B

Comment: @anuj have you try this?? if yes, then what is the issue you facing now?

Comment: i am not understanding @Ravi B

Comment: You want to hide and show the headerview, so on click on button i have reload the table, which calls all methods of tableview again and in `heightforheader` I have checked if book yes means you want to hide headerview it will return 0 to height of view so it will automatically hide the header and viceversa for the visible true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153952/discussion-between-anuj-and-ravi-b).